# Removing html with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to delete a whole block of html with  javascript(no jquery).

**Source**

```
 <li uib-dropdown="" class="dropdown hidden-xs">
                <a uib-dropdown-toggle="" class="dropdown-toggle pointer" "="" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <img width="22" title="  - xyz@gmail.com" height="22" class="img-rounded profile-img" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/edft80b9a51f775c8ee562ca89345318b"> &nbsp;
                                <!-- <b class="caret"></b> -->
                  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu small-dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="https://app.example.com/#/account">Account</a></li>
                  <li><a href="https://app.example.com/#/account/billing">Billing</a></li>
                  <li><a href="https://app.example.com/#/account/team">Team</a></li>
                  <li><a href="https://app.example.com/#/account/plans">Plans</a></li>
                  <li class="hidden-lg"><a class="pointer" title="Ask us a question, report a bug or suggest a feature!" href="mailto:help@example.com">Contact</a></li>
                                <hr>
                  <li><a target="_self" href="https://app.example.com/logout"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
```

**Desired result**
The whole block of code should be remove

**My attempt**

```
document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown hidden-xs').innerHTML = '';
```

Comment: Do you not need a . Between he dropdown and hidden-xs

Comment: You have a syntax error as modox2 pointed out. See: MDN [Document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) for correct usage. Use a loop to delete the content of multiple elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns array-like object, so you need to access element by index:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown hidden-xs')[0].innerHTML = '';
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip for the new JS like...what if i want to remove every instanace of `class="dropdown hidden-xs"` ,

Comment: I mean is there a shoter way than using a loop

Comment: @user2650277 I think it is not possible without a loop. E.g. `elements.forEach(function(el) { el.innerHTML = ''; })`

Answer (score 1):

To set the html of all elements with that class to `''`, you'll need a loop.

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown hidden-xs'), function(el) {
    el.innerHTML = '';
});
```

Or, to really delete them, use:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown hidden-xs'), function(el) {
    el.parentNode.removeChild(el)
});
```